# Are there any viable ways of using the particle system with micro-displacement?

Tags: particles, displacement, experimental-features

I've watched a couple of videos dealing with micro-displacement. On one of them, the author had mentioned that it doesn't support the particle system as of now. I know this is an experimental feature and would possibly solved by the next major release of Blender. Are there any suggestions for substitutes or any other methods for adding a particle system to such a mesh?

Answer (score 1):

I had figured out how to solve that problem. I used a duplicated mesh without the adaptive displacement modifier and scaled it to a point where it barely beneath the mesh. However, I used that technique on a standard human mesh, so it may not work as properly on a highly irregular mesh unless that mesh matches the projected displacement.