# Particle system adapting to adaptive displacement?

Tags: displacement

is there a way the particle system can adapt its height to the correct height of the adaptive displacement height map?

Currently my grass is rather beneath or below my ground because they still follow the flat non adaptive ground... How to remedy this? How the particles can follow each bump and variation in height of the terrain without losing its adaptive faculty?

Its quite problematic for nature scene...

Thanks

Comment: Simple answer is no. There is no way (that I know about) to make particles work with adaptive subdivision. This is still experimental feature and it is working only in render mode. Also I'm not sure but for a long time I didn't read a thing about further development of it.

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95183/make-particles-follow-true-material-displacement and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69661/are-there-any-viable-ways-of-using-the-particle-system-with-micro-displacement

Comment: Thanks, quite sad... What about fixing the particle to a height map with no adaptive subdivision but juste subdiv , make it so that it stay  that way when removing subdiv and switching it to adaptive? Can we do this?